# This is my Computer project and i am getting error and i don't know how to fix

Tags: python

```
#this t_movie function is used to select movie name

def t_movie():
   global f
    f = f+1
    print("which movie do you want to watch?")
    print("1,movie 1 ")
    print("2,movie 2 ")
    print("3,movie 3")
    print("4,back")
    movie = int(input("choose your movie: "))
    if movie == 4:
#in this it goes to center function and from center it goes to movie function and it comes back here and then go to theater
      center()
      theater()
      return 0
    if f == 1:
      theater()

# this theater function used to select screen
def theater():
    print("which screen do you want to watch movie: ")
    print("1,SCREEN 1")
    print("2,SCREEN 2")
    print("3,SCREEN 3")
    a = int(input("choose your screen: "))
    ticket = int(input("number of ticket do you want?: "))
    timing(a)

# this timing function used to select timing for movie

def timing(a):
    time1 = {
        "1": "10.00-1.00",
        "2": "1.10-4.10",
        "3": "4.20-7.20",
        "4": "7.30-10.30"
    }

    time2 = {
        "1": "10.15-1.15",
        "2": "1.25-4.25",
        "3": "4.35-7.35",
        "4": "7.45-10.45"
    }

    time3 = {
        "1": "10.30-1.30",
        "2": "1.40-4.40",
        "3": "4.50-7.50",
        "4": "8.00-10.45"
    }

    if a == 1:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time1)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time1[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    elif a == 2:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time2)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time2[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    elif a == 3:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time3)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time3[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    return 0

def movie(theater):
    if theater == 1:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 2:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 3:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 4:
        city()
    else:
        print("wrong choice")

def center():
    print("which theater do you wish to see movie? ")
    print("1,Inox")
    print("2,Icon")
    print("3,pvp")
    print("4,back")
    a = int(input("choose your option: "))
    movie(a)
    return 0

# this function is used to select city

def city():
    print("Hi welcome to movie ticket booking: ")
    print("where you want to watch movie?:")
    print("1,city 1")
    print("2,city 2 ")
    print("3,city 3 ")
    place = int(input("choose your option: "))
    if place == 1:
      center()
    elif place == 2:
      center()
    elif place == 3:
      center()
    else:
      print("wrong choice")

city() # it calls the function city
```

Please any one just point out Mistake i can't find it

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I have put f = 0 outside the function and it's work and give one space to global. Global was not perfect in function.

#this t_movie function is used to select movie name

```
f = 0

def t_movie():
    global f 
    f = f+1
    print("which movie do you want to watch?")
    print("1,movie 1 ")
    print("2,movie 2 ")
    print("3,movie 3")
    print("4,back")
    movie = int(input("choose your movie: "))
    if movie == 4:
#in this it goes to center function and from center it goes to movie function and it comes back here and then go to theater
      center()
      theater()
      return 0
    if f == 1:
      theater()

# this theater function used to select screen
def theater():
    print("which screen do you want to watch movie: ")
    print("1,SCREEN 1")
    print("2,SCREEN 2")
    print("3,SCREEN 3")
    a = int(input("choose your screen: "))
    ticket = int(input("number of ticket do you want?: "))
    timing(a)

# this timing function used to select timing for movie

def timing(a):
    time1 = {
        "1": "10.00-1.00",
        "2": "1.10-4.10",
        "3": "4.20-7.20",
        "4": "7.30-10.30"
    }

    time2 = {
        "1": "10.15-1.15",
        "2": "1.25-4.25",
        "3": "4.35-7.35",
        "4": "7.45-10.45"
    }

    time3 = {
        "1": "10.30-1.30",
        "2": "1.40-4.40",
        "3": "4.50-7.50",
        "4": "8.00-10.45"
    }

    if a == 1:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time1)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time1[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    elif a == 2:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time2)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time2[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    elif a == 3:
        print("choose your time:")
        print(time3)
        t = input("select your time:")
        x = time3[t]
        print("successful!, enjoy movie at "+x)
    return 0

def movie(theater):
    if theater == 1:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 2:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 3:
        t_movie()
    elif theater == 4:
        city()
    else:
        print("wrong choice")

def center():
    print("which theater do you wish to see movie? ")
    print("1,Inox")
    print("2,Icon")
    print("3,pvp")
    print("4,back")
    a = int(input("choose your option: "))
    movie(a)
    return 0

# this function is used to select city

def city():
    print("Hi welcome to movie ticket booking: ")
    print("where you want to watch movie?:")
    print("1,city 1")
    print("2,city 2 ")
    print("3,city 3 ")
    place = int(input("choose your option: "))
    if place == 1:
      center()
    elif place == 2:
      center()
    elif place == 3:
      center()
    else:
      print("wrong choice")

city() # it calls the function city
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared the variable `f` in the function `t_movie`, the `f` will not be available outside the function `t_movie`. That means the `f` will only be defined whenever the function `t_movie` is invoked, after processing through the  `t_movie`, the `f` variable will be deleted.

**Solution**: In order to make the `f` variable available for all of the functions, consider declaring it outside of the method (the same level as the invoked main method, in your case, it's `city()`)